# Element type is invalid: expected string or class but got undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working through a tutorial and have run into the following error on and iOS simulator.

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from 
the file it’s defined in.
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is going on. I've tried importing both { LoginForm } and LoginForm, but neither work. If I comment out `{/*<LoginForm />*/}` in App.js, it works fine.

index.ios.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('accessss', () => App);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import LoginForm, { Header } from './components';
import firebase from 'firebase';
const config = require('./../config/firebase.config.js');

class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Header headerText="Authentication" />
                <LoginForm />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {


};

export default App;
```

LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Card, CardSection } from './';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;

{/* Also tried export { LoginForm }; */}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm exporting 4 other components and they are working fine.

Comment: Have you tried `export LoginForm;`? (without the curly braces). Another potential solution is removing `export default LoginForm` and changing the class definition to `export default class LoginForm extends Component`

Comment: Changed to `import { LoginForm } from './components/LoginForm.js';` and it worked with `export default LoginForm;`

For some reason it didn't like the idea of not specifying the file to import.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your `index.js` file inside your components folder? Without an `index.js` file inside a directory, default imports won't work for directories. You could either do this:

`/components/index.js:`

```
import LoginForm from './LoginForm.js'
import {Header} from './Header.js'

export Header
export default LoginForm
```

or in your App.js, do this:

```
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'
import {Header} from './components/Header'
/* ... */
```